# WPF Bind or trigger element to a separate datagrid update

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, datagrid

In wpf I have a TabControl that contains a DataGrid which is bound to an observable collection.

I want an animation to trigger when the following conditions are met:

1) The datagrid's collection updates

2) The tab is not selected.

Essentially I want the tab to flash if it's containing datagrid gets updated while the user has another tab selected.

```
<TabItem x:Name="tab1" Header="Tab 1">
    <TabItem.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
            <Style.Resources>
                <Storyboard>
                    <!-- Animation --> 
                </Storyboard>
            </Style.Resources>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=tab1, Path=IsSelected}" Value="False"/>
                        <!-- Should I have a condition for datagrid1 updating?  -->
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard .../>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
                </MultiDataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TabItem.Style>
```